# How to verify dll signature with java?

Tags: java, dll, digital-signature

I have a signed dll (by Visual Studio) and I am able to use it in Java but i also want to check the signature so the user can't replace him.

I have found little info on how to check a dll signature (JAR signatures keeps popping up).

Does anyone know a solution?